# Инициализировать переменные массива одним значением без цикла?

Tags: c++, массивы

**1)** Скажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли на С++ как нибудь инициализировать все значения массива одним и тем же значением, не используя цикл?
Или можно ли как-то по-другому решить следующую проблему...
У меня в классе есть массив

```
static bool result[M];
```

Я хочу, чтобы первоначально все значения данного массива были `true` . В процессе, мне потребуется их менять. 
Была идея сделать цикл

`for (i = 0; i < M; i++) result[i] = true;`

в конструкторе класса, но тогда ведь он будет выполняться при каждом создании объекта... Значит так делать не стоит..? 
Подскажите пожалуйста, что сделать)

--

**2)** И вопрос 2(еще более дурацкий).
Допустим, у меня есть глобальная переменная `const int N = 5`.
Мне нужно создать глобальную переменную `const int M`, которая будет равно 10 в степени N. Функцией `pow` в таком случае пользоваться нельзя, как тогда можно это сделать?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) Вы не можете избежать инициализации. Но вы можете объявить статическим не массив, а целый объект класса с конструктором:

```
template<size_t M>
struct InitializedArray
{
    bool data[M];
    InitializedArray()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) data[i] = true;
    }
}

...
static InitializedArray<M> result;
```

2) Вам подойдёт вот такой [трюк с шаблоном](http://ideone.com/5YWjll):

```
const int N = 5;

template <int M>
struct power_of_10
{
    static const int value = 10 * power_of_10<M - 1>::value;
};

template<>
struct power_of_10<0>
{
    static const int value = 1;
};

const int M = power_of_10<N>::value;
```

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ!
Не могу понять способ...
Где мне объявлять эту структуру? И как мне это поможет создать массив в классе?

Comment: @777Julia777:
* структуру объявляйте в любом доступном header'е. (полностью, не разбивая не объявления и реализацию, так как template)
* там, где у вас раньше было `static bool result[M];`, напишите `static InitializedArray<M> result;`. Обращаться к элементам вместо `result[i]` надо будет `result.data[i]`.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо, поняла.
А касательно второго вопроса, ведь мне нужно будет пользоваться переменной M не только в этом классе, значит так делать нельзя?

Comment: @777Julia777: обновил ответ.

---
Хотелось бы услышать комментарий поставившего минус.

Comment: @VladD, я не ставила, если вы это имеете ввиду...
За пример еще раз спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли :)

Comment: @777Julia777: Что вы, я не имел в виду вас.

Comment: @минусатор: Какие-нибудь комментарии будут?

Answer (score 5):

Не зная M, массив можно проинициализировать только дефолтными значениями типа, т.е. `false`. В случае статического или глобального массива это происходит автоматически, в случае не статического можно возпользоваться одним из эквивалентных способов:

```
   bool arr[10] = {0}; // Работает даже в С
   bool arr[10] = {false};
   bool arr[10] = {};
```

Проставлять значения при каждом вызове конструктора конечно не стоит. Я вижу несколько вариантов решения вашей проблемы.

---

**Простое решение.** Можно поменять смысл, который несут значения вашего массива на противоположный. Например, если это был массив isResourceAvailable, переименовать его в isResourceBusy. Тогда дефолтная инициализация будет правильной.

---

**Универсальное решение.** Создать метод (возможно статический) для инициализации статических переменных, и убедиться, что этот метод будет иметь эффект только при первом вызове. А потом вызывать его при конструировании каждого объекта. Выглядеть это будет как-то так:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass() {
    MaybeInitializeStatic();
  }
private:
  static void MaybeInitializeStatic() {
    static bool initialized;
    if (initialized)
      return;
    initialized = true;
    std::fill_n(arr, M, true);
  }

  static bool arr[M];
};
```

Стоит отметить, что такое решение подходит только для однопоточной программы. Чтобы сделать его thread-safe, нужно добавить синхронизацию:

```
  static void MaybeInitializeStatic() {
    static bool initialized;
    static std::mutex mutex;
    if (initialized) {
      return;
    } else {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
      if (initialized) return;
      std::fill_n(arr, M, true);
      initialized = true;
    }
  }
```

---

**Еще одно универсальное решение**, даже лучше предыдущего. Вызывать функцию во время инициализации другой статической переменной.

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass() {}
private:
  static void InitializeStatic() {
    std::fill_n(arr, M, true);
  }

  static bool arr[M];
  static int unused;
};

int MyClass::unused = (InitializeStatic(), 0xDeadBeef);
```

Тут не нужна ни синхронизация, ни проверка того, что функция будет вызвана только один раз.

Comment: > Не зная M, массив можно проинициализировать только дефолтными значениями типа, т.е. false.

То есть, написать так

    bool arr[10] = {true};

нельзя?

Comment: Cпасибо большое за ответ!
Работает) Разобралась)

Comment: @KoVadim: Можно, но результат будет не такой, как ожидалось: http://ideone.com/KCdAam

Comment: @dzhioev: По идее, `M` можно достать как `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)`.

Comment: @VladD, а вы юмор мой не словили:) в случае bool arr[10] = {false}; Вы также инициализируете только первый элемент.

Comment: @KoVadim: Правда? Я не знал. Мне казалось, что (по крайней мере) в C++ 11 [не так](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members, the remaining members are initialized by empty lists, which performs [value-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

Comment: тега с++11 нет:)

Comment: @KoVadim, я наверное коряво написал, имелось ввиду, что если бы знали, что M будет всегда равно, например, 5-ти, то можно было бы написать:

    bool arr[5] = {true, true, true, true, true};

Comment: @KoVadim, "в случае bool arr[10] = {false}; Вы также инициализируете только первый элемент" -- это неправда. Такая конструкция инициализирует все 10 элементов в false. "bool arr[10] = {true}" -- первый элемент в true, остальные в false. Если же просто написать "bool arr[10]", то в arr будет мусор.

Comment: В gcc (но не g++) можно написать так

    char a[5] = {[0 ... sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) - 1] = 1};


    typedef char bool;
    #define true 1
    bool a[5] = {[0 ... 4] = true};

 
      char

Comment: @avp: А в C99 `#include <stdbool.h>` и `_Bool`.

Comment: @dzhioev, есть еще одно вполне универсальное и понятное всем решение.

В самом начале программы пишем

     int main (int ac, char *av[]) {
         MyContext_t *init_context = global_init_and_configure(ac, av);
         ....
     }

вызов функции, которая вручную инициализируе все, что требуется.

Comment: @avp, ну а зачем заставлять пользователя класса делать лишние телодвижения, если можно сделать, чтобы все само работало?

Comment: @dzhioev, сами даже кошки не родятся. 

Никто за Вас класс не напишет. Так что, количество телодвижений (если писать грамотно) получится одинаковым, а вот ясность программы... (тоже зависит от писателя).

Answer (score 3):

1) Если Вы боретесь за скорость, замените цикл на

```
memset(result, 0xFF, sizeof(result))
```

В любом случае кто-то должен выставить единички в памяти, из ниоткуда они там не возьмутся. Так пусть хотя бы это будет делаь функция, задача которой - делать это и делать максимально эффективно.

Comment: очень плохая идея. во первых, лучше писать `sizeof(result)*sizeof(bool).` `sizeof(bool)` обычно равно 1, но пункт 5.3.3 стандарта говорит, что это личное дело компилятора.

> in particular, sizeof(bool), sizeof(char16_t), sizeof(char32_t), and sizeof(wchar_t) are implementation-deﬁned.

0xFF скорее всего будет true, но далеко не факт.  Но раз уж тег с++, тогда правильно писать так:

    std::fill_n(result, sizeof(result), true);

Comment: В смысле? Sizeof в байтах размер возвращает.
А fill не предлагаю потому что STL и скорость идут далеко не всегда рука об руку. Например, я сталкивался с тем, что зануление vector<bool> (его методом assign) нереально медленное. Потому что инициализация идёт по отдельным битикам и какой бы умный компилятор не был, он это не схлопнет до *(int *)... = 0. Я не говорю, что моя идея хорошо соответствует идеологии С++, я наоборот хочу показать, что если бороться за скорость, то придётся замарать руки

Comment: std алгоритмы очень хорошие. Очень часто, зануление массива они сводят к банальному memset. а `vector<bool>` - это особый случай.

Comment: @Михаил М, выставлять байтики вручную совсем небезопасно, т.к. в итоге может получиться невалидный bool. Вот я набросал следующий код:

    #include <cstring>
    #include <iostream>
    
    int main() {
      bool f;
      bool g;
      memset(&f, 0xf0, sizeof(bool));
      memset(&g, 0x0f, sizeof(bool));
      std::cout << (f && g) << std::endl;
    }

У меня он, в зависимости от уровня оптимизации и компилятора, выводит то 0, то 1.

Comment: @dzhioev, естественно, теоретически, - не безопасно! Практически - не знал, про бывают такие проблемы с 0xF0 и 0x0F, спасибо! Давайте новый вопрос на эту тему откроем? У меня есть подозрение, что проблема не в разных положениях единичек, а в том, что компилятор не распознал, что лезут в память переменных

Comment: Похоже, что для `bool` g++ "честно" анализирует младший бит (независимо от уровня оптимизации). 

Если `bool` заменить на char, то любое ненулевое значение выглядит как `true`.

Comment: @avp: Запись в `bool` значения, отличающегося от бинарного представления `true`/`false` есть undefined behaviour.

Comment: @VladD Я, кстати, в свое время, когда следил за [вот этим вот тредом](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518951/engineered-bool-compares-equal-to-both-true-and-false-why), так и не смог найти место в стандарте, где говорится, что инициализация памяти, отведенной под POD-тип, значением, невалидным для этого типа, является UB. Можете ткнуть пальцем, если у вас найдется минутка? :)

Comment: @Котик: я перечитал параграф 3.9 в [свежем драфте](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3691.pdf), там упоминается (абзацы 2, 3) лишь копирование _из_ объекта куда-то и потом назад или в другой объект. Более ничего не сказано => явного требования нет => UB. (Надеюсь, моя логика верна.)

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, По [ссылке][1] пишут, что стандарт C допускает trap representations для стандартных типов, которые могут вызвать UB даже при чтении. В C++ стандарте встречаются упомининия trap, и даже есть std::numeric_limits<T>::traps, но внятного описания, что это значит, я не нашел.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6725981/409863

Comment: @dzhioev: например, вот что: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/19/60162.aspx

Comment: Классная статья! Не знал про 65-й битик. Хотя, ИМХО, это теперь на совести разработчиков компиляторов обходить такие грабли, вызванные "хрупкостью" архитектуры процессоров

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать `std::vector` вместо массива, у него есть конструктор, который заполняет его нужным значением:

```
std::vector<bool> result(M, true);
```